# Custom ROM on Sony Ericsson Xperia Pro (MK16i)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms, rom-flashing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I do really hate the system that Sony Ericsson has placed on the top of Android and I would like to have ICS (but no problem if not possible or recommendable). I have tried googling and looking around for a couple of days to find how and what custom ROM I could install on my telephone, but I have had no luck in this venture.

Does anybody here know about a custom ROM I could install on my telephone? Preferably as clean as possible or similar to HTCs system and ICS if possible and usable.

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1445819) ROM based on CM 9.0?

Comment: I do not seem to find out how to install the ROM, do you have a guide for that? :)